# JMS Broker Options for CloudBees?

Tags: java, jms, rabbitmq, activemq-classic, cloudbees

Does CloudBees offer any JMS hosting or any 3rd party JMS hosting (like IronMQ)? After perusing their [Partner Ecosystem](http://www.cloudbees.com/platform/ecosystem/tech-partners.cb) pages and developers docs, I don't see anything of the sort. I'd like to deploy a web app to CloudBees but will need messaging, and something like RabbitMQ or ActiveMQ.

I know I could always ship my WAR with an embedded instance of ActiveMQ running inside of it, but that kind of defeats the purpose of scalability in my mind: the harder the queues are working, the slower my app is going to become, and it would be nice to delegate the messaging work to a broker residing on another machine.

Also, it would be *most sweet* if such a messaging service had a free tier like so many of the other CloudBees tech partners offer...

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no official partner (yet) to provide messaging service, but you for sure can use a SaaS MQ service from your cloudbees application, even not being an official partner, for sample http://www.cloudamqp.com/ to get RabbitMQ -as-a-service, Iron.io or Amazon SQS. The only consideration is to ensure this service is hosted on Amazon, so your application won't suffer network latencies to access the MQ broker - most SaaS run on AWS anyway

free tier option is another consideration, depends on partner business model... (CloudAMQP has one)

Comment: Thanks @nicolas de loof (+1) - any idea as to when CloudBees will be integrating with a SaaS MQ provider? I saw a CloudBees article from 2011 talking about this, so it's obviously something that's been kicked around for a while...